# Word for Party *Steward*?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes a person who is usually not too drunk and takes care of the rest of the folks at a party?

Typically, they're the ones who drag the sloshed ones back to beds, clean up the house and generally maintain a bit of sanity.

Comment: _Designated driver_ is commonly used to refer to a person who abstains from drinking so he or she can drive the less sober guests home, but I don't know if that could be extended to the other duties you describe.

Comment: _Chaperone_ comes close, but probably isn't close enough: 
1. A guide or companion whose purpose is to ensure propriety or restrict activity ...
2. An older person who attends and supervises a social gathering for young people ... [AHDEL]

Comment: or *Host*, perhaps.

Comment: [_Drunksitter_](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drunksitter) is used in slang.

Comment: Drunksitter seems to be the best fit. @ermanen - Could you put it down as an answer?

Comment: In my college fraternity these were the insurance-mandated *sober monitors*, but no one would be assigned that title outside of an institutional setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Drunksitter*** is used in slang.

> A person at a party or a bar who stays sober or nearly sober and prevents their drunk friends/guests from doing anything stupid
>
> [[Urbandictionary/drunksitter]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drunksitter)
>
> ---
>
> Looking after your drunk friends when you are the only sober one. Keeping an eye on them, escorting them everywhere, keeping them out of trouble and sometimes cleaning them up. This should also include making sure they get home safe with all the belongings they brought with them.
>
> [[Urbandictionary/drunk-sitting]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drunk-sitting)

Answer (score 4):

Where are you from? I want to party with you guys!

Generally, the *host* and/or *hostess* will try to remain relatively sober and in control. In cases where they don't, there is not usually anyone else expected to "reign in" the chaos. Often, the appearance of law enforcement is the only sign that will make everyone aware that they are out of control. "We had a party and the cops came," is a popular description of a wild celebration.

The only person who is really *required* to take responsibility, is a person deemed the "designated driver". It is their job to stay sober in order to transport the intoxicated, or otherwise make arrangements for them to get home.

(They will not put you to bed or clean up the mess, though) (US)

Comment: .+1 The common meaning of sober is "not drunk" — designated driver need to be sober.  Quiet and restrained.

Comment: Often we host parties at a friend's parent's house and hence the place cannot be razed to the ground or completely trashed. The parties are usually all-nighters with little to no trace of the party being left behind in the morning. The chaperone/drunksitter ensures things don't go too outta hand. Also, designated drivers are rarely needed since people are sober enough to drive back in the morning.

Comment: Pet peeve: it's "rein in" (as in, exert control over your horse via the use of reins), not "reign in".  Otherwise, +1.  :-)