# A person who doesn’t drink much to control others?

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I think I've heard it some time ago but I can't remember. Is there an English word or idiomatic expression for "A person who doesn’t drink much to control others"?

Comment: Do you mean a person who rarely drinks to control others, but frequently drinks for other reasons? Or do you mean a person who would drink a large quantity, but chooses to drink a small quantity because doing so lets them control others?  Neither of these sound likely, but I don't see another, more plausible, interpretation of your question.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Consider a group of friends that drink together, one of them drinks less to keep others in check. Is there any expression for that person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be thinking of [drunksitter](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=drunksitter) - like a babysitter for adults :)

> drunksitter
>
> A person at a party or a bar who stays sober or nearly sober and prevents their drunk friends/guests from doing anything stupid
>
> My friend turned 21 yesterday and I had to be the drunksitter.

[See this post about drunksitting](https://www.theodysseyonline.com/drunksitters)

There is also the term [designated driver](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/designated-driver?s=ts)

> a person who abstains from alcoholic beverages at a gathering in order to be fit to drive companions home safely.

I've just noticed that a [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217391/word-for-party-steward) was answered on ELU previously

Comment: +1 just because of *drunksitter*. ;)